# SQL\laravel обновление данных через временную таблицу

Tags: sql, laravel

Участок кода Создает временную таблицу **temp_product_properties**

```
Schema::create('temp_product_properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('shop_code')->index();
            $table->string('product_code')->index();
            $table->decimal('price_stock', 10, 2);
            $table->temporary();
            });
```

В эту таблицу записывается относительно большой объем строк (800 000+ )
Далее стоит задача обновить данные в основной таблице **product_properties** .
Обновить необходимо поле **price_stock** , Нужная запись находится по **shop_code** и **product_code**

Для обновления используется "сырой" запрос

```
    UPDATE product_properties
            join temp_product_properties
            on temp_product_properties.shop_code = product_properties.shop_code
            AND temp_product_properties.product_code = product_properties.product_code
            SET product_properties.price_stock = temp_product_properties.price_stock
            WHERE product_properties.shop_code = temp_product_properties.shop_code
            AND product_properties.product_code = temp_product_properties.product_code
```

На тестах с небольшим количеством данных все относительно быстро отрабатывает. Но при увеличении до условных 100 000 записей - уже существенно долго. В связи с этим возник вопрос - правильно ли составлен запрос на обновление данных ?

Comment: *правильно ли составлен запрос на обновление данных ?* Нет. Какой великий смысл повторять одни и те же условия связывания дважды? *существенно долго.* Ну так проиндексируйте перед апдейтом временную таблицу по полям связывания... надеюсь, что нужный индекс у обновляемой таблицы уже имеется.

Comment: так там же связывание по двум разным полям или имеется в виду, что можно опустить условие where?

Comment: *имеется в виду, что можно опустить условие where?* Угу. А то прям масло масляное... ведь после связывания нет ни одной объединённой записи, не отвечающей этим условиям.